# pythod OOP methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have been learning python and currently learning OOP python and saw this on W3 schools but  dont understand how it works

```
class Person:
  def __init__(mysillyobject, name, age):
    mysillyobject.name = name
    mysillyobject.age = age

  def myfunc(abc):
    print("Hello my name is " + abc.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)
p1.myfunc()
```

Doesn't the method have to reference current instance of the class to access variables of class so  confused as to why the method can use `abc` and not my `sillyobject` and be able to compile. Any explanation would be so helpful. Sorry if this is really obvious am newish to python

Answer (score 2):

The name of the argument variable in the method does not matter to python.

Python will always put the reference of the current instance into the first  of the method arguments. Using `self` is just a convention and it is just an ordinary variable name. However it's a very well accepted convention so please use `self` unless you are trying to highlight a point with code such as in the W3 schools page.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense  you explained that so well